# Filtering timestamp query on firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter timestamp from firebase in ionic. What i am trying to do is, i want to filter all timestamps that haven't passed today's date, which are schedules. Basically if a schedule has already been completed, i want to retrieve it from Firestore. If its still scheduled then i don't need to retrieve it. My problem is that i can't really get any timestamp at all.
In order to do so, i am doing my query inside my constructor. Here it is.

```
myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();



    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
                let db = firebase.firestore();
                var auxint = 0;
                this.dataAux
                let auxString = '[';
                db.collection('Usuario').where("Deletado", "==", false).where('DataCriacao', '<', this.myDate).get().then(res => {
                  res.forEach(item => {

                    auxint++;
                    auxString += '{"id":"' + item.id + '","Usuario":' + JSON.stringify(item.data()) + '}';

                    if (res.size != auxint)
                      auxString += ', ';
                  })
                  auxString += ']';
                  this.dataJSON = JSON.parse(auxString);

                  console.log(this.dataJSON);
                }).catch(err => {
                  console.log('algum erro ' + err);
                });

        }
```

How i am doing to display firestore data

```
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let data of dataJSON">
      <ion-item>
    <h3>DataCriacao: {{data?.DataCriacao}}</h3>
    <p>DataUpdate: {{data?.DataUpdate}}</p>
    <p>DELETADO: {{data?.Deletado}}</p>
    <p>EMAIL: {{data?.Usuario?.Documento?.email}}</p>
    <p>ID: {{data.Usuario.Documento?.id}}</p>
    <p>NOME: {{data.Usuario.Documento?.nome}}</p>
    <p>SENHA: {{data.Usuario.Documento?.senha}}</p>
    <p>TELEFONE: {{data?.Usuario?.Documento?.telefone}}</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options>
```

Comment: You'll need to indicate what exactly `this.date` is, and the contents of some documents that should be matching your query.

Comment: I thought i was doing that in-fact, would you elaborate on how should i do that?

Comment: Can you plz post the database structure and your model class.

Comment: @Raj https://imgur.com/a/wTcT4N1 https://imgur.com/a/i3rR4iw

Comment: Also, another observation: https://imgur.com/a/eZZXnVL I noticed my screen is printing out an empty [] array type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed my screen is printing out an empty [] array type.

This is because you are comparing String and Timestamp data using >. This is not a valid comparison and hence no document from collection is retrieved giving you empty array.

Instead you have to keep both the data types same. You should keep the current date in Date format only. And the Timestamp returning from firestore is also in date format.

```
myDate: String = new Date();
```

So, now you can use where query to compare them.

Comment: Alright, but how will i query and compare them after? since im handling the return function right after with .then

Comment: You can try with normal comparison method using > or <. Like                 db.collection('Usuario').where("Deletado", "==", false).where('DataCriacao', '<', this.myDate).get().then(res => ....And don't convert Date to String..

Comment: Great. Cheers bro